# Android Cursors and multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading, android-cursor

I want to understand what is the philosophy behind the cursors in Android because I am having problems in using them from different threads.

Theoretically there is a set of objects and there is a pointer to an element from that set which can run over that set. This idea is somehow similar, for example, to container iterators in C++. Is the cursor **just an iterator** over a set of objects or it is an **iterator together with the data set?**

As a result, another question arises - **having a cursor, which iterates over a set of objects, can I create another cursor over the same set of objects?**

The problem is following: I have a cursor which is conceptually the **model** part of my architecture, and I have 2 different **views** which visualize that model. So I give this cursor to two views (one is list view and another one is a custom view). Each view periodically moves the cursor to some row and gets different data from different columns of it. The bad thing is that they do this in different threads, so when one calls `moveToPosition()` and then `getString()` then the other can move it to another row between these two calls so everything is messed up.

The solution would be to give them two independent pointers over the same data set, for example, creating another Cursor from one I have. But **if** the concept behind the Cursor objects is combining these 2 responsibilities - data set and iterator - into one class, then this is not possible. Let me know if you see the big picture and understand the ideas behind Cursors.

Comment: Why are you using different threads for your two views?

Comment: One is a regular list view which uses the main thread, the other one is a custom view implemented with opengl so its rendering is done in a separate gl thread.